# Filter 2D numpy rows based on multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If `data` is 2D array of shape (10,3). This:

`data = data[data[:,-1] != 1]`

should remove any row that ends with 1 (remove by value). What if I want to remove based on **multiple values**, say 1,2,4, how can I do that? Trying `data = data[data[:,-1] != [1,4,2]]` didn't work with me. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: try this:   idx = (data[:,-1] != 1) * (data[:,-1] != 4) * (data[:,-1] != 2); data = data[idx].

Comment: Just to extend on the above, if instead of a fixed number of values you want to exclude all those that belong to another given list, this can be done by `idx = np.isin(data[:, -1], [1, 4, 2])`.